# JQuery checkbox check

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Suppose I have 3 checkboxes (one,two,three). Now I want that if I click checkbox one then checkbox two and three will uncheck.

Another example: if I click checkbox two then checkbox one and three will uncheck.

And if I click checkbox three then checkbox one and two will uncheck.

### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="one"><label>One</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="two"><label>Two</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="three"><label>Three</label>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check").click(function(){
        $(".check").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $(".check").removeAttr("checked");
    });
});
```

Comment: why not use a radio button instead

Comment: So how about three different classes?

Comment: @L10 - The requirement specified is not quite what radio buttons do because with radio buttons the user can't uncheck all of them.

Comment: @nnnnnn - yea that's true...but the OP was asking to select only one..so i suggested that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio buttons are a better fit for what you're trying to do. But if you must use checkboxes, the following should work:

```
$(".check").click(function(){
    $(".check").not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

Comment: You should do this or radio buttons. Avoids a checkmark flicker which my answer below would have.

Answer (score 0):

Answer Part 1: This is precisely what radio buttons were designed for, they have this behavior by default.

Answer Part 2: the click function should look like this:

```
$(".check").click(function(){

    $(".check").attr("checked", false);
    $(this).attr("checked",true);

});
```

Comment: The requirement specified is not quite what radio buttons do because with radio buttons the user can't uncheck all of them.

Comment: Good point, although he doesn't specify that the user should be able uncheck all of them, that would be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

For a group of options where only one is to be checked, use [radio buttons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button#HTML) or a [single-select box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select):

```
<input type="radio" name="check" value="one"><label>One</label>
<input type="radio" name="check" value="two"><label>Two</label>
<input type="radio" name="check" value="three"><label>Three</label>
```

If you really need to stick with your checkbox situation, you can do this:

```
$(".check").change(function(){
    $(".check").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true)
});
```

Notice that I'm binding to the `change` event instead, as the user may click on the label or something (I'm not sure if a synthetic click is triggered on the checkbox in this case.)

On a side note: Your [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) elements are missing `for` attributes.

Comment: Clicking a label triggers a click event on the associated input (though as you noted, the OP's labels aren't associated).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $cbs = $(".check").click(function() {
        $cbs.not(this).prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```